# @Html won't place /

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following snippet:

```
<td class="col-md-1">          
    @if (ViewBag.isUser)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Price)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Price) @Html.DisplayNameAttributeFor(Model.Currency) / @Html.DisplayNameAttributeFor(Model.PriceUnit)
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.BootstrapEditorForWithoutLable(m => Model.Price)
    }
</td>
```

However, it is throwing an error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected
```

I have tried to put the ; after the first row:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Price);
```

..but that wont work. Not sure where it wants it? I'm new to MVC, not really sure about how to render HTML/C# in the view. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is `BootstrapEditorForWithoutLable`?  some custom function?

Comment: Use `@Html.Raw("/")`

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke, works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but will take only one minute to find out:

```
<td class="col-md-1">          
    @if (ViewBag.isUser)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Price)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Price) @Html.DisplayNameAttributeFor(m.Currency) / @Html.DisplayNameAttributeFor(m.PriceUnit)
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    }
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Html.Raw("/") as proposed by Stephen Muecke works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code and hope it's works.

```
<td class="col-md-1">
    @if (ViewBag.isUser)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Price)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Price) @Html.DisplayNameAttributeFor(Model.Currency) / @Html.DisplayNameAttributeFor(Model.PriceUnit);
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.BootstrapEditorForWithoutLable(m => Model.Price)
    }
</td>
```